# Retrieving data from SQL on PHP and showing it on HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a little problem with HTML and SQL.

I am in a login session, I am saving some user info via SQL, and the function `saveProfile` works fine.

What I want to do though, is that when the form below submits, it runs the database updating function, but also inserts the newly registered string submitted by the form right there where the form was.

For instance, if the user submits `www.google.com`, I would like the updateProfile function to go get the newly submitted `www.google.com` from somewhere (I've tried getting it directly from

```
$x = $_POST["fbProfile"]
```

but can't manage to retrieve that value) and insert it back there. Is there any way to do this? Thank you very much

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['loggedin'])
{
    header("location:index.html?problem=notLoggedin");
    exit;
}
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$surname = $_SESSION['surname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$profile = $_SESSION['profile'];
$course1 = $_SESSION['course1'];
$course2 = $_SESSION['course2'];
$course3 = $_SESSION['course3'];
$course4 = $_SESSION['course4'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="En-US">
<head>

<body> 
<div class="container">
<table >

<tr>
<td><p><b>My Facebook profile:</b></td>
<td><p id="editprofile"><?php print($profile); ?></p></td>
<td><p onclick="return editprofilefunction()" id="editprofileblank"><a href>Edit</a></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
function editprofilefunction() {
document.getElementById("editprofile").innerHTML = '<form name="emailForm" method="post" onsubmit="return !!(saveProfile() & updateProfile())"><input   type="text" name="fbProfile" placeholder="Insert your Facebook URL"/> <input   id="submit" type="submit" value="Save"></form>';
document.getElementById("editprofileblank").innerHTML = "";
return false;      
}

function saveProfile() {


<?php
    $x = $_POST["fbProfile"];

    define('DB_NAME', 'DATABASENAME');
    define('DB_USER', '1956218_students');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password');
    define('DB_HOST','HOST');
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "UPDATE  `DATABASENAME`.`Students` SET  `Fbprofile` =  '$x' WHERE  `Students`.`Email` = '$email'  ";       

 ?>
}

function updateProfile() {
document.getElementByID("editprofile") = ********PROFILE STRING I HAVE JUST   SAVED***********;
return true;
}


</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _You have a large problem, you dont understand how the web works_ You cannot run PHP like you would javascript. Javascript runs in the browser but PHP only runs on the server i.e. before the page gets delivered to the browser

Comment: Solution is to post form via ajax and return needed value from php script. It will be handled in ajax succes function.

Answer (score 0):

Follow my firstgoogled [example](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/).

Idea is to post form via ajax and return needed value from php script. It will be handled in ajax succes function.

Comment: Hi userlond, thanks very much for the comment. I think it works, I applied it to my code, but now the SQL Update will update all rows that don't have an email in them. I think it's not reading the $email variable anymore. I retrieved this variable at the top, as you can see, since it is a session variable. I tried opening a session also in the php script that in the link you gave me is called response.php, but it still won't work. Any advice? Many thanks!

Comment: I I were u i would check `$_SESSION` content. Insert `var_dump($_SESSION); exit;` to response.php after opening the session.

If there is no $_SESSION['email'], check the place you insert this value into $_SESSION (it should be login page).

If inserting seems ok, check for rewriting it anywhere below.